# Comma splice in message for nonexistent tag wiki

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki, wording, grammar

In the Tagged Questions list for a tag that has no tag wiki yet (see https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new to find current examples), the message at the top reads

> The [bleep-bloop-blop-blorp](/questions/tagged/bleep-bloop-blop-blorp) tag has no wiki summary, can you help us create it?

The comma should be a semicolon.

Comment: For a second, I thought that was a real tag...

Comment: Or the comma should be replaced by a period.